# I want to create Python Dash app to watch a directory over ftp , extract data from the file and plot it in real time

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, plotly, plotly-dash

I am working on a project on which I have to monitor a ftp directory for any new files which appear , once a new file appears I want to extract data from and plot the results in real time so far I have sorted out the ftp function that monitors the directory , for testing purpose I am using my phone as a test ftp server and I have created a function which uploads a new file every n seconds :

```
from ftplib import FTP
from time import sleep
import os


ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect('192.168.1.109', 2221)
ftp.login('android', 'android')
ftp.cwd('/test_folder')
folder = 'C:\\Users\\QC\\Desktop\\sample_files_to_upload'

for file in os.listdir(folder):
    fp = open(folder + file,'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % os.path.basename(file), fp, 1024)
    sleep(2)
    fp.close()
    sleep(2)
    print("File {} uploaded sucessfully".format(file))
```

I also have a function which watches the directory for any new files which appear in the directory and as soon as the file appears it copies it on the local machine performs data extraction prints the output and removes the file:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from time import sleep
import time
import os

def monitor_ftp():
    ftp = FTP()
    ftp.connect('192.168.1.109', 2221', 21)
    ftp.login('android', 'android)
    ftp.cwd('/test_folder')
    print("Connection Established {}".format(ftp.getwelcome()))
    direct = 'C:\\Users\\QC\\Desktop\\local_temp_directory\\'
    old_files = ['1']
    #print(old_files)
    while True:
        try:
            new_files = ftp.nlst()
            #print(new_files)
            #print(new_files)
            if len(old_files) != 0 and new_files != old_files:
                changes = [i for i in new_files if i not in old_files]
                #
                # print(changes)
                for x in changes:
                    filename = str(direct + x)
                    localfile = open(filename, 'wb')
                    ftp.retrbinary('RETR'+' ' + x , localfile.write, 1024)
                    localfile.close()
                    
                    xcorr = extract_function(filename)
                    
                    print("updating data ***************************************************")
                    print("found new file---> {}".format(str(filename).split('\\')[-1]))
                    print("Calculating cross-correlation")
                    print("*****************************************************************")
                    print(" ")
                    sleep(3)
                    os.remove(filename)
                    
                a = time.perf_counter()
            
            if time.perf_counter() > a + 20:
                print("Done Waiting")
                break
            old_files = new_files
            
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            ftp.quit()
```

I have also created a basic test_dash app :

```
import dash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from app import app



app = dash.Dash(__name__) 


app.layout = html.Div( 
    [ 
        dcc.Graph(id = 'live-graph', animate = True), 
        dcc.Interval( 
            id = 'graph-update', 
            interval = 10000, 
            n_intervals = 0
        ), 
        html.Div(dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.H2(id='check_update_div', children='check ' ))
        ]) )
    ] 
) 

@app.callback( 
    Output('check_update_div', 'children'), 
    [ Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals') ] 
) 
  
def update_graph_scatter(n): 
    
    print('one loop done ')
    
    a = monitor_ftp()
    return ("this is  X {}".format(a))
```

I want to tie everything together and create a dash app which monitors the ftp directory and plots the result of data extract , currently I don't have a graph in my app, I have just put a div which I want to update with the file name for every new file that appears in the folder , but I am not sure how to combine these functions together. Can you please help.

Edit:

I have got a working example which shows that ftp inside the callback function prevents the function from returning anything , if ftp is outside the return function then callback returns and updates the div every n_intervals

```
import dash 
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc 
import dash_html_components as html 
import plotly 
import random 
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
from collections import deque 
from ftplib import FTP 
from time import sleep

#ftp otside the function and function works fine 
#Deactivae this part and activate ftp inside the function , and function 
#stops returning anything and div is not updated every n_interval 
ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect('10.199.44.240', 21)
ftp.login('display')
ftp.cwd('/home/display/test_qc')
print("Connection Established {}".format(ftp.getwelcome()))
direct = 'C:\\Users\\QC\\Desktop\\Gunlink_local\\'

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Interval( 
            id = 'graph-update', 
            interval = 10000, 
            n_intervals = 0
        )
    ]),
    html.Div([
        html.H1(id='print_value', children="Output Value"),
    ])
])


@app.callback( 
    Output('print_value', 'children'), 
    [ Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals') ] 
) 
  
def update_value(n):
    
    # ftp inside the function prevents the function from returning anything
    # Div is not updated every n_interval
    '''
    ftp = FTP()
    ftp.connect('10.199.44.240', 21)
    ftp.login('display')
    ftp.cwd('/home/display/test_qc')
    print("Connection Established {}".format(ftp.getwelcome()))
    a = ftp.nlst()
    '''

    a = ftp.nlst()

    sleep(2)
    print('one loop done ')
    return ("this is  X {}".format(a))


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the [interval](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval) component.

Dash cannot do constant updates, like running that `while` loop nonstop, but you can have the interval set to fire a callback every X seconds. Using that callback, you can check the FTP server on that schedule for updates.

Check out [this page](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates) of the docs for some good examples of using it to create a live-updating page.

Comment: I have got a working example which shows that ftp inside the callback function prevents the function from returning anything , if ftp is outside the return function then callback returns  and updates the div every n_intervals

Comment: I edited my question to add an example which shows that doing ftp inside callback every n_intervals prevents the callback from returning anything

Comment: Does it raise an error, or fail silently? The interval looks like 10 seconds, which I would think is enough, but perhaps is not. If you change it to 60 seconds, does it run? If you can run a debugger and place a breakpoint where the FTP call starts, try stepping through each line to see what is going on.

Comment: It actually doesn't fail it just doesn't return anything , sometimes the number of files can be more and the function will need much more time than 10 seconds to process and extract data , is there any way that I can tell dash to only fire the n_interval counter only after the function has finished , or alternatively I can fire a callback only once which watches the directory in while loop and performs the extraction, giving output to a hidden div , appending extracted data to data frames and I can write dcc.Interval invoked functions just to update my graphs plotting those dataframes?

Comment: Will it be possible to run a while True loop based function from within dash?

Comment: The interval component will run every n milliseconds, and all you can do is change that interval. You can run a loop in a callback, but the callback will only output once regardless of how many times the loop cycles. You could trigger the function manually with a button, so it only updates when asked.